# pd.rolling_max and min with groupby or similar

Tags: python, pandas

Using the following code I am able to capture the rolling high and low of my data in the `H1_high`and `H1_low` columns.

```
data["H1_high"] = pd.rolling_max(data.High, window=60, min_periods=1)
data["H1_low"] = pd.rolling_min(data.Low, window=60, min_periods=1)
```

This gives the following output:

```
                    Open    High    Low Last    Volume  H1_high H1_low
Timestamp                           
2014-03-04 09:30:00 1783.50 1784.50 1783.50 1784.50 171 1784.50 1783.5
2014-03-04 09:31:00 1784.75 1785.75 1784.50 1785.25 28  1785.75 1783.5
2014-03-04 09:32:00 1785.00 1786.50 1785.00 1786.50 81  1786.50 1783.5
2014-03-04 09:33:00 1786.00 1786.00 1785.25 1785.25 41  1786.50 1783.5
2014-03-04 09:34:00 1785.00 1785.25 1784.75 1785.25 11  1786.50 1783.5
2014-03-04 09:35:00 1785.50 1786.75 1785.50 1785.75 49  1786.75 1783.5
2014-03-04 09:36:00 1786.00 1786.00 1785.25 1785.75 12  1786.75 1783.5
2014-03-04 09:37:00 1786.00 1786.25 1785.25 1785.25 15  1786.75 1783.5
```

What I would like to do is only capture the `H1_high`and `H1_low` between the following times:

```
daystart = '9:30'
IB_end = '10:29:59'

IB_session = data.between_time(daystart,IB_end, include_start=True, include_end=True)
```

and do this on a daily basis showing the `H1_high`and `H1_low` then carrying forward (FFill) the last value from  `IB_end = '10:29:59'` to the end of the day (16:14:00).

So here is desired output for `H1_high` `H1_low` columns:

```
                    H1_high H1_low
2014-03-04 10:29:00 1786.75 1783.5
2014-03-04 10:30:00 1786.75 1783.5
2014-03-04 10:31:00 1786.75 1783.5
```

final value from `10:29:59` fills forward until end of day:

```
                    H1_high H1_low
2014-03-04 16:14:00 1786.75 1783.5
```

then new day starts again with fresh values:

```
                    H1_high H1_low
2014-03-05 09:30:00 1788.00 1783.00
```

Comment: When the days starts again, do you want the roll to include information from the prior day?  If not, do you want the roll to only begin when there is adequate data (60 minutes worth), meaning, your rolling data only starts at 10:30?

Comment: Hi @piRSquared.  No roll from prior day.  The data I want is only from first hour and starts instantly at 9:30 each day.

Comment: Basically it is the high and low of the first hour of the day (9:30 - 10:30) and it refreshes each day.  I want the 10:29 value to forward fill for the rest of the day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `datetime.time` and filter your index

```
import datetime

high_low_xt = lambda df: pd.concat([df.High.cummax(), df.Low.cummin()], axis=1)
tidx = pd.date_range('2016-09-14', '2016-09-16', freq='T')

start = datetime.time(9, 30)
end = datetime.time(10, 30)
eod = datetime.time(18, 14)

bidx = tidx[(tidx.time >= start) & (tidx.time < end)]
didx = tidx[(tidx.time >= start) & (tidx.time <= eod)]

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(len(tidx), 2), tidx, ['High', 'Low'])
df1 = df.ix[bidx].groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('D')).apply(high_low_xt)

df1.reindex(didx, method='ffill')
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks but does this not only give a static daily output?  I mentioned above I need the 10:29 value to forward fill for the rest of the day.  I need to keep this as an intra day dataset and not resample to daily.

Comment: Thanks @piRSquared.  But in the first hour the high and low changes but is your code giving a static output during this period?  The FFill is only after 10:30.  Until then the values are changing.

Comment: For the first hour (9:30-10:30) the max and min is as per my original post above showing values changing as new high and low are seen. Please see the output at top of the post. Then after 10:30 it needs to ffill the high and low from this period until the end of the day. thanks

Comment: To be honest I'm sure how to use this with my data.

Comment: Do I need a tidx = pd.date_range('my dataframe start, 'my dataframe end', freq='T')?

Comment: @adele set `tidx = your_dataframe.index`